# Pass Model from one component to other in Angular 5

Tags: angular5

### Problem

I am using angular 5 for SPA. I have 2 component Parent Child. I called an API from Parent component and cast the response of that API into Model. Now I want to pass that model into other component. 
I already use @Input to get the model but it render in the view but not catch into the component. when I console.log that model I passed it shows me undefined.

### Code

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog} from "@angular/material";

import {SpecDetailsServ } from "../services/SpecDetailsServ";
import {SpecDetailsModel} from "../models/SpecDetailsModel";
import {Quote} from "../models/Quote";
import {ServiceDialogComp} from "./ServiceDialogComp";
import {QuoteDetailsDialogComp} from "./QuoteDetailsDialogComp";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spec-details-comp',
  templateUrl: '../views/spec-details.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../assets/css/component.css']
})

export class SpecDetailsComp implements OnInit {
    customerId = 1;



    getSpecDetails: Array<SpecDetailsModel>;
    showLoader = true;
    getQuotes: Quote;

    constructor(private getspecdetails: SpecDetailsServ, private matdialog: MatDialog) {
        this.getspecdetails.getSpecDetails(1).subscribe(res => {
            var resNew:any = res;
            this.getSpecDetails = resNew.result;
            this.showLoader = false;
        })
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

### Parent View

```
<app-quote-details [getSpecDetails]="getSpecDetails"></app-quote-details>
```

### Child Component

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {SpecDetailsComp} from "./SpecDetailsComp";
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog} from "@angular/material";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-quote-details',
    templateUrl: '../views/quote-details.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../assets/css/component.css'],
})

export class QuoteDetailsDialogComp {

   //this is the model i wanna pass to other component with data init
    @Input() getSpecDetails: Array<SpecDetailsModel>;

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is answer working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `*ngIf="getSpecDetails"` to your child component.

Your child components `init` is happening before you get response from server.

When you add `ngIf` child component's `init` will trigger only after `getSpecDetials?` in defined.

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to add `ngOnChanges` angular lifecycle hook on child. This will update your child component whenever there are any changes in the input. using `*ngIf` is another solution but this will update only once -during initialization and changes wont be reflected. Check this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components) that explains it very easily.

Comment: You have your concepts wrong, child component and it's view will update irrespective of whether you add `ngOnChanges` hook, its like an event you can use to keep tab on value changes , changes will still happen and component is updated with latest values from `@Input` even when don't use `ngOnChanges` hook. OP wanted to have defined value at `init` so `*ngIf` is correct solution here.